# C# Keyboard hook freeze

Tags: c#, windows, keyboard, hook, freeze

I'm making a program that uses a hook to monitor the pressed keys in Windows. In that program, I handle that key in a Windows Forms environment. When I press a key, my whole Windows freezes for like 3 seconds, the same counts for the Visual Studio debugger, the callstack is showing up after 3 seconds.

The code: http://pastebin.com/aZmP5vWr
(I removed some irrelevant parts)

I think it is going wrong on line 67 because on line 91 it calls CallNextHookEx again, am I right?

How do I solve this?

Comment: This happens when your callback doesn't return quickly enough.  Windows puts up with that for a while, then kills to hook to keep the OS usable.  It is unclear from the snippet what your hook actually does, there's no obvious subscriber for OnKey.  Setting a breakpoint on the callback method is certainly good enough to get this to occur.

Comment: I add images to a list, save them to the harddisk and show them in a panel. I know that is the problem. The question is how I solve it.

Comment: That's not a very obvious reason for the problem.  If it is really that slow then you'd have to change a registry key to increase the timeout.  Not exactly a fix, Windows is still dead.  You will have to make it faster, spin off the job to a worker thread for example.

Comment: I will look for some information about worker threads, the ones I have found don't look that simple to me. Thanks for now.

Comment: I found out, that even when I don't do anything at all, it still freezes. I randomly tried to change CallNextHookEx to IntPtr.Zero but that didn't do a thing either. So, I'm stuck again.